# pop up a message box in jsp / servlet

Tags: jsp

I am working on a JSP/servlet application.
I want to pop up a message alert box in JSP/servlet after inserting user data to database table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after data insert in DB you need to use

```
request.setAttribute("alertMsg", "data add sucess");
```

then redirect to jsp by using  RequestDispatcher

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");  
rd.include(request, response);
```

Now in jsp use scriptlet tag like

```
<% String message = (String)request.getAttribute("alertMsg");%>
```

And you will get a alert message.

Now in javascript alert show like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var msg = "<%=message%>";
    alert(msg);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks rahul for ur valuable answer.The message was pop up but the new question is index.jsp page become blink.

Answer (score 0):

try this within jsp to pop show message after inserting value into db

```
<%
String s1=request.getParameter("username");
String s2=request.getParameter("passward");
int a=0;
try{
     a=st.executeUpdate("insert into tablename values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"')");
if(a==1){

        %>
        <p>well come for you</p>
        <%
        }
        else{
            %>


            <p>not well come for you</p>
    <%  }
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

%>
```